# Is there a way to fill string with characters at some specific indices?

Tags: java, string

There is a string "hello-world!". Any character except A-Z and a-z has to stay in the same place, but letters have to be reversed. So, output would be "dlrow-olleh!".

I used string builder to design the solution, but I am curious if a string of length 12 can be declared and its characters filled in indices 5 and 11, then fill remaining with reversed letters.

Any other techniques or ideas to perform the same would be appreciated.

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i=S.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            String c = ""+S.charAt(i);
            if(c.matches("[A-Za-z]")) {
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++) {
            String c = ""+S.charAt(i);
            if(!c.matches("[A-Za-z]"))
                sb.insert(i,c);
        }
```

I got the output this way, but is there any way to use String here instead of StringBuilder?

Comment: Yes: transform your string to a char array, then modify the char array as you want to, then create a new string from this char array. You can't modify the original string: strings are immutable.

Comment: Note that Strings are immutable in Java. If you "change" a String, you are creating a new object. StringBuilder (or char arrays, as @JBNizet suggested) will be more efficient.

Comment: You would have to work on an array of char, as mentioned by the comment above. But, a StringBuilder is just a wrapped char[] with additional functionalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `String` in the way you suggest, because `String` is immutable.

Another option, instead of `StringBuilder`, is to use a raw array of `char`. You know that the resultant string will have the same length as the source string, so you can do it like this:

1. Create an array using [String.toCharArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--).
2. Iterate from both ends simultaneously using indices `i` and `j`. Start index `i` from 0 moving forwards, and j from array length - 1, moving backwards.
3. Check the elements at i and j for a letter using [Character.isLetter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-char-). If it's not a letter, just skip it by advancing i forwards or j backwards.
4. Swap the array elements at i and j.
5. Repeat while i < j.
6. Create the new string using [`new String(charArray)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-)

As this looks like an exercise, I'll leave the actual coding to you.

Caveat: the above only works for strings where the Unicode code points are in the Basic Multilingual Plane (i.e. most strings to you and me). It won't work for tricky situations containing certain characters such as smileys (for more info on this potential problem, see https://dzone.com/articles/the-right-way-to-reverse-a-string-in-java).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer the question in detail. Appreciate.